# Django 1.11 don't included urls.py

Tags: python, django

Hello I'm working in my first Django App and I have the next problem:

> The included URLconf 'eventus.urls' does not appear to have any
>   patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue
>   is probably caused by a circular import.

```
.
├── eventus
│   ├── eventus
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── db.sqlite3
│   │   ├── settings
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   │   ├── base.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   │   └── local.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── base.py
│   │   │   ├── local.py
│   │   │   ├── prod.py
│   │   │   └── staging.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   └── myapps
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── events
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── __pycache__
│       │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │   ├── forms.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   ├── admin.py
│       │   ├── apps.py
│       │   ├── forms.py
│       │   ├── media
│       │   │   └── events
│       │   │       ├── evento.png
│       │   │       ├── evento2.png
│       │   │       ├── evento2_a0yEovu.png
│       │   │       ├── evento3.png
│       │   │       ├── evento3_IufcnS5.png
│       │   │       └── evento_HFKQ1lo.png
│       │   ├── migrations
│       │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│       │   │   ├── 0002_auto_20170924_2140.py
│       │   │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   │   └── __pycache__
│       │   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │       ├── 0002_auto_20170924_2115.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │       ├── 0002_auto_20170924_2140.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   ├── models.py
│       │   ├── static
│       │   │   ├── css
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css.map
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap.css
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap.css.map
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css.map
│       │   │   │   └── estilos.css
│       │   │   ├── fonts
│       │   │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│       │   │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│       │   │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│       │   │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
│       │   │   │   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
│       │   │   └── js
│       │   │       ├── bootstrap.js
│       │   │       ├── bootstrap.min.js
│       │   │       └── npm.js
│       │   ├── templates
│       │   │   ├── base.html
│       │   │   └── events
│       │   │       ├── base_events.html
│       │   │       ├── index.html
│       │   │       └── panel
│       │   │           ├── crear_evento.html
│       │   │           ├── detalle_evento.html
│       │   │           ├── editar_evento.html
│       │   │           ├── eliminar_evento.html
│       │   │           ├── navbar.html
│       │   │           └── panel.html
│       │   ├── tests.py
│       │   ├── urls.py
│       │   └── views.py
│       └── users
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── __pycache__
│           │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│           │   ├── actions.cpython-36.pyc
│           │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│           │   └── models.cpython-36.pyc
│           ├── actions.py
│           ├── admin.py
│           ├── apps.py
│           ├── migrations
│           │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│           │   ├── __init__.py
│           │   └── __pycache__
│           │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
│           │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│           ├── models.py
│           ├── tests.py
│           └── views.py
└── requirements
    ├── base.txt
    ├── local.txt
    ├── prod.txt
    └── staging.txt
```

my file events/urls.py is :

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import IndexView, MainPanelView, CreateEvent, EventDetail, EventEdit, EventDelete


urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^$',views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^$',IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),


    url(r'^panel/$', MainPanelView.as_view(), name="panel"),
    url(r'^panel/evento/nuevo/$',CreateEvent.as_view(), name="nuevo"),
    url(r'^panel/evento/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',EventDetail.as_view(), name="detalle"), 
    url(r'^panel/evento/editar/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',EventEdit.as_view(), name="editar"),
     url(r'^panel/evento/eliminar/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',EventDelete.as_view(), name="eliminar"),   
]
```

my file is events/views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .models import Event, Category
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, CreateView, DetailView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from myapps.users.models import User
from .forms import EventoForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, reverse_lazy
# Create your views here.

def login(request):
    return render(request, "login.html", {})

#def index(request):
#   events = Event.objects.all().order_by('-created')[:6]
#   categories = Category.objects.all()
#   return render(request, 'events/index.html', {'events': events, 'categories': categories})

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'events/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['events'] = Event.objects.all().order_by('-created')[:6]
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context


#def main_panel(request):
#   #organizer = request.user.username
#   events = Event.objects.filter(organizer__username='').order_by('is_free', '-created')
#   cantidad_eventos = events.count()
#   return render(request, 'events/panel/panel.html', {'events': events, 'cantidad': cantidad_eventos})


class MainPanelView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'events/panel/panel.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MainPanelView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['events'] = Event.objects.filter(organizer__username='').order_by('is_free', '-created')
        context['cantidad'] = context['events'].count()
        return context


#def crear_evento(request):
#   if request.method == 'POST':
#       modelform = EventoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
#       if modelform.is_valid():
#           organizador = User.objects.get(pk=3)
#           nuevo_evento = modelform.save()
#           nuevo_evento.organizer = organizador
#           nuevo_evento.save()
#           return redirect ('events_app:panel')
#   else:
#       modelform = EventoForm
#
#   return render(request, "events/panel/crear_evento.html", {'form': modelform})


class CreateEvent(CreateView):

    form_class = EventoForm
    template_name = 'events/panel/crear_evento.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('events_app:panel')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.organizer = User.objects.get(pk=3)
        return super(CreateEvent, self).form_valid(form)


#def detalle_evento(request, evento_id):
#   event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=evento_id)
#   return render(requestr, 'events/panel/detalle_evento.html', {'event': event})

class EventDetail(DetailView):

    template_name = 'event/panel/detalle_evento.html'
    model = Event


#def editar_evento(request, evento_id):
#       event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=evento_id)
#
#       if request.method == 'POST':
#           modelform = EventoForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=event)
#           if modelform.is_valid():
#               modelform.save()
#               return redirect(reverse('events_app:panel'))
#           else:
#               modelform = EventoForm(instance=event)
#
#           return render(request, 'events/panel/editar_evento.html', {'form': modelform, 'event': event})

class EventEdit(UpdateView):

    template_name = 'events/panel/editar_evento.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy(reverse('events_app:panel'))
    model = Event
    form_class = EventoForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.organizer = User.objects.get(pk=3)
        return super(EventEdit, self).form_vaslid(form)



#def eliminar_evento(request, evento_id):
#   event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=evento_id)
#
#   if request.method == 'POST':
#       event.delete()
#       return redirect(reverse('events_app:panel'))
#
#   return render(request, 'events/panel.eliminar_evento.html')


class EventDelete(DeleteView):

    template_name = 'events/panel.eliminar_evento.html'
    model = Event
    success_url = Ureverse_lazy('events_app:panel')
    context_object_name = 'event'
```

my urls.py is :

```
from django.conf.urls import  url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('myapps.events.urls', namespace="events_app")),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}
            ),
        ]#
```

my events/models.py is :

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.conf import settings
# Create your models here.

class TimeStampModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug =slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save (*args,**kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Event(TimeStampModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    finish = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'events')
    is_free = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    amout = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    organizer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug =slugify(self.name)
        super(Event, self).save (*args,**kwargs)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Assistant (TimeStampModel):
    Assistant = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    event = models.ManyToManyField(Event)
    attended = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    has_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.assistant.username , self.event.name)


class Comments(TimeStampModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.user.username, self.event.name)
```

And the error is the next :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/CursoProDjango/eventus/eventus/urls.py", line 27, in <module>
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}
  File "/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 85, in url
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

my base.py is the next:

```
"""
Django settings for eventus project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from unipath import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(3)


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '70r=ho4co205hed75q!)am+dnqi=lj(98$lnadxmgf2n(s&_qi'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition
DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

LOCAL_APPS = [
    'myapps.events',
    'myapps.users',
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + LOCAL_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'eventus.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'eventus.wsgi.application'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

And I don't know what is the problem, because before it working fine, but now I don't know what is the problem, I only change my events/urls.py from views based in functions by views based in class, but in the file are comment the old views before the new views in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traceback shows that an error is occuring on line 97 of `events/views.py`:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy(reverse('events_app:panel'))
```

You can't call `reverse` when setting `success_url` for a view. It causes the Django to try to reverse the url before it has loaded the url config, which leads to the "does not appear to have any patterns" error message.

The solution is to use `reverse_lazy`. You have `reverse_lazy(reverse(...))` which doesn't make sense. Change it to just use `reverse_lazy`:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('events_app:panel')
```

Your second error "view must be a callable" is because your code to serve the media files uses the string `'django.views.static.serve'`. This is out of date and does not work with Django 1.10+. Update it to [match the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development):

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I need use reverse, because it is a form and I need send data in a POST, there will be other problem, not this.

Comment: Trust me, it doesn't make sense to do `reverse_lazy(reverse(...))`. The traceback is telling you that the error is occuring on that line.

Comment: Alasdair thanks for your help, but I have the same problem.

Comment: You have `No module named 'myapps.urls'` because you changed the code to `url(r'', include('myapps.urls'),` as @Julipels suggested. That didn't work, because you don't have a file `myapps/urls.py`, so you should change it back the way it was before.

Comment: Your question and traceback show you *still* have `reverse_lazy(reverse(...))` in your code. Change it to `reverse_lazy(...)`. You also have `success_url = Ureverse_lazy('events_app:panel')` which is a bug.

Comment: I change it, but I continuos with problems

Comment: Try to debug the errors yourself. The traceback says that the line causing the problem is `url(r'^panel/$', MainPanelView.views.as_view(), name="panel"),`. That url pattern is clearly different from your other ones. Remove the `.views` that is causing the problem, to change it to  `MainPanelView.as_view()`.

Comment: Next time you make a big change like this, try to break it down into smaller steps. If you changed the views to class based views one at a time, then you'd make fewer mistakes, and it would be easier to debug.

Comment: you are right, because, you know that I change to it because urls with class view and fiction views working at same time didn't work fine.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to have class based views and function based views at the same time.

Comment: It's entirely possible to have class based views and function based views at the same time. Your latest error has nothing to do with function or class based views - it is because you are using a string `'django.views.static.serve'`. I could have told you how to fix that hours ago if you had included the full traceback when you updated your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545743/django-1-11-error-with-change-from-views-based-in-fuction-to-views-based-in-clas).

Comment: Yes I know it, but in my other questions we didn't it, for this reason I change all my views to a class views. I think with this will be working fine.

Comment: And what is the solutions, because I don't know. 
And sorry because I am learning to work with stack overflow too.

Comment: I've already updated the question with the solution. Remove the `if settings.DEBUG` block that contains the incorrect url pattern, then add `+ static(...)` to your `urlpatterns` like the docs shows.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to explain.

Comment: what is the different to put `+static(..)` after urlpatterns main or after urlpattern debug.

Comment: The `static()` helper already checks for `settings.DEBUG`. So when you change your code to use it, you should remove the `if settings.DEBUG:` block from your code, and just add `static(...)` to your url patterns.

Answer (score -1):

in base.py add

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ['myapps.events',]
```

Comment: I have installed it